# Heroku rails app stay in staging mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I created a staging instance some month ago on Heroku.
Now I want to turn it back to production.

So classic stuff

```
$ heroku config:add RAILS_ENV=production RACK_ENV=production
> RACK_ENV:  production
> RAILS_ENV:  production
```

Printing config with "heroku config" tell everything is fine, sadly :

```
$ heroku run console
...
> Loading staging environment (Rails 3.2.3)
```

If I print ENV variable, RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV are still in production

```
$ Rails.env
=> "staging"
$ ENV["RAILS_ENV"]
=> "production"
```

I double check the code. Nothing force at any point a staging env.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have duplicate RAILS_ENV variables set? Check all your vars . I think it is just heroku:config to view all environment variables.

Comment: I already checked that "Printing config with 'heroku config' tell everything is fine". It show me only one variable set to production ... We finally decided to create a new instance to see if the problem come from heroku or not

Comment: humm... interesting. Did firing a new instance fix it?